# Get Total Active ASP.NET Session Count via WMI

Tags: asp.net, session, wmi

How can I get a count of the total number of active ASP.NET sessions via WMI? I'm using ASP.NET 4.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the WMI query - "Select SessionsActive from Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET_ASPNETApplications"

Edit - included link on accessing remote machines

This should answer the comment on remote machines,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257337(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to run that against a list of remote machine names, or do I have to RDP into each machine and run that locally?

Comment: thanks - is there a way to specify the remote host via powershell instead of compiled code?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309377(v=vs.85).aspx - is this any help?

Comment: I have tried the same, works fine but the session count does not decrease. Any reason??????????????

Comment: @Amit have you got an open question with more details?

Comment: I get back all zeroes for every "column" returned by this query. I'm working from a VBS script though but still getting zero for everything on what I know is a very active web server. I am running this as administrator from cmd.exe http://www.activexperts.com/admin/scripts/wmi/vbscript/0433/